Nikon Lens dropping focus
I use my camera for sports photography and midway through an event on Sunday my Nikon Nikkor AF-P 70-300mm VR ED lens stopped focusing correctly. It have not dropped or hit it the lens just stopped focusing correctly mid use.
It will focus at 100mm and 300mm. Between 100-300mm you can hear the autofocus make half an attempt but doesn't end up focusing and between 70-100mm there's no noise at all. The focus point also does not light up in red when the shutter button is pressed down between 70-100mm.
I have followed with minor troubleshooting so far such as cleaning contacts/sensors etc. I've tried a different lens (also a 70-300mm but the DX VR version) which has absolutely no trouble at all focusing throughout the ranges.
What is causing this and is it fixable at home?

If you Google for that lens and focus problem, it seems that similar problems occurred to other users as well.
From quickly going through them, it seems most lenses were sent in for repair and had parts exchanged after which they worked again.
Some people recommend cleaning the contacts and retest, however as the problem only occurs at certain focus lengths, I doubt that it would help.
One Example: https://www.flickr.com/groups/4118578@N22/discuss/72157666636531659/
Sorry, but it seems that your lens is malfunctioning and needs repair.

Thank you for that article. The last person who commented makes the most sense! It’s very likely a motor part issue. Absolute shame as I’ve had this happen on two identical lenses now. This one is thankfully in warranty so I’ll be sending it back. Thank you!
